# The deleted folder still appears in git bash when using ls command

Tags: git, git-bash

For a C# project, I used `git rm -r --cached obj/` and `git rm -r -f obj/` command to remove `obj/` from the directory, but after that when I used `ls` I could still see `obj/` folder in the directory. When I tried to use `git rm -r obj/` command again, it told me `fatal: pathspec 'obj/' did not match any files`, but I could still use `cd obj/` to see all the files that were supposed to be deleted.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached) (without `--cached`) should remove those files from the working tree (your disk) as well as the index, provided they were not ignored in the first place.

Check if:

- there was an ignore rule already in place

  ```
  git check-ignore -v obj/a_file_inside_obj
  ```
- if *all* files are still there, or only a few (which might not be deleted, because already used by an active thread)

Answer (score 1):

Every file you use in Git has up to three simultaneously active copies.  For concreteness, let's talk about the file named `obj/a` (I'll just *assume* there was such a file).

There is one copy of `obj/a` in three places when you start:

- One is—or might be, anyway—in the *commit* that you selected with `git checkout master` or `git switch master` or however it is that you selected a branch and therefore a commit.
- A second copy of `obj/a` in Git's *index*.  The index, which is also called the *staging area*, holds a copy<sup>1</sup> of each file ready to go into the *next* commit you will make.  The copy in the index is first put there by your `git checkout` or `git switch` command.  It stays there until you do something to or about it.
- Finally, the only copy of `obj/a` that you can *see* is an ordinary file in your *work-tree* or *working tree*.

The reason for the committed copy is that every commit holds a copy of *all* of your files, as the commit's snapshot.  This copy, once made, can never be changed at all.  No part of *any* commit can ever be altered: all commits are frozen for all time.

The reason for the work-tree copy is that the committed copy is not only frozen for all time, it's also compressed into a special Git-only format, that only Git can use.  This is good for archival but useless for actually getting any work done.  Git has to extract it and turn it back into a normal everyday file, so that you can use it.  This is also why your work-tree is called "work-tree" or "working tree": it's where you do your work.

The *index* copy is the one that doesn't really have an obvious reason to exist.  But Git has one.<sup>2</sup>

When you ran:

```
git rm -r --cached obj/
```

Git removed the *index* copy of `obj/a`.  The committed copy *can't* be removed: it's in a commit, and no part of any commit can ever be changed.  The *work-tree* copy of `obj/a`, which is the one you can see and use, was left behind, because *you told Git to leave it alone* when you said `--cached`.  So now you're down to *two* copies of the file, instead of three.

If you want to get rid of the *work-tree* copy of the file, use your computer's "remove a work-tree file" command, whatever that is (`rm`, perhaps).  Had you told Git earlier `git rm -r obj/` you would have instructed Git to remove *two* copies: the one in the index, and the one in the work-tree.  Now that the index copy is *gone*, `git rm` won't remove the work-tree one, because the work-tree copy is now an *untracked file*.  So now you need to use the non-Git command.

(Alternatively, you could `git add obj/a`, which will copy the file *into* the index.  Now it will be in all three places again, and now `git rm obj/a` will remove both the index and work-tree copies.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, what's in the index is not an actual *copy* of the file, but rather the file's name and mode and a *reference to* the file's data, ready to be put into a new commit.  But unless you start inspecting the index's content directly with `git ls-files --stage`, or using `git update-index` to change the index's content, the difference here is not all that important.

<sup>2</sup>That is, Git has a copy of the file there—although see footnote 1.  Git has a reason, too: it makes it easier for Git to be Git.  There are systems that work a lot like Git, but don't bother with an index.  They just use the work-tree copy as the proposed next commit.  That works, but it's slower and doesn't offer some of the features that Git does.

Answer (score 0):

`git rm` just removes files from git. If you want to remove the files from the file system, you should use `rm -rf ./obj`.